# How to fetch felter value from url to show block?

Tags: views

I have created a block in drupal 7 using better expose filter.. I need to fetch all filtered value from url and need to show block data according to filtered value.
For example: mydomain.com/your-view-path?field_a=valuea&field_b=valueb

Comment: and what is your question? what have you tried, what research have you done, what worked, what didn't, how did it not, etc.

Comment: I need to use field_a and fied_b value in my block. And need to show regarding data..

Comment: again, what have you tried, what research have you done, what worked, what didn't, how did it not, etc. Drupal Answers is not a place to find people to do the work for you, it's a Q&A site, and I still don't see a viable question

Comment: I used contextual filter .. But its not giving me results.

Comment: this is getting painful. what settings did you use? can you show a screen shot of the set up, what version of Drupal, what version of Views, is it a page or a block, are there other filters or relationships involved, etc. I've wasted enough time on this, you won't hear from me again